How to Scale Translation of Multiple Objects (without affecting object scale)?
I have the following three objects, equal distant from each other (from world center) along the XY plane.  I want to move them away from each other uniformly, as noted:

I want to essentially 'scale' the distance between them along the XY plane (as if an invisible balloon is inflating, pushing them apart, so to speak).
Looking for the simplest method, hopefully one that doesn't require Geometry Nodes.
One solution I tried which doesn't work is to attach them all to a circle using a Child Of constraint, and then scale the circle.  I was hoping the size of the circle would displace the distance between them, but this also scales each object, which I don't want.
I thought there used to be a way you could translate multiple object locations using Scale, but in a way where it only moves the objects and doesn't actually change their scale, but I can't figure it out.

Set your transform to affect locations only. Int the top right, where it says "Options". Then if you haven't applied any of the individual objects' rotation, if you press S to scale, followed by the XYZ axis letter twice, it will scale them each on their own local axis.

Ah man thanks @Jakemoyo it was so simple!  I searched and searched for this answer but I couldn't find it. Do you want to make this an answer so I can mark it, just in case anyone else as forgetful as me comes along?

Set your transform to affect locations only. In the top right, where it says "Options". Then if you haven't applied any of the individual objects' rotation, if you press S to scale, followed by the XYZ axis letter twice, it will scale them each on their own local axis.


It's amazing how I still forget easy things like this. Thank you!
